# Bash simple one-liner to auto-login ssh

Tags: ssh, login

I'm looking for a relatively simple one-line command for `bash` that will disable the password prompt on future `ssh` logins (or preferably only the next `ssh` login), as well as a way to reverse it (the reversal doesn't have to be a one-liner).

Is this possible?

Comment: Another option would be a tool called `sshpass`.   Once installed you just need to set the `SSHPASS` variable with your password and then you can use `sshpass -e ssh user@host` and wont be prompted with a password.  You can add something like `read -p "What is your ssh password" SSHPASS` to your `.bash_profile` or something if you want to set it at login and not have to worry about it afterwards.

Comment: Note that the instructions in all current answers and comments do not _disable_ password authentication. Enabling public key authentication means you don't have to type a password to log in, but it does not _disable_ password authentication, _anyone could still use it_. An important distinction for security!

Comment: @marcelm The first option is what I am looking for.

Comment: @marcelm I'm looking to allow access without typing a password at any point.

Answer (score 11):

Simply `ssh-copy-id username@host.example.com` for one-stop shopping for key-pair authentication.

If you don't already have a keypair to use, generate one:  `ssh-keygen && ssh-copy-id username@host.example.com`.

Comment: So, I would type something like `ssh-keygen && ssh-copy-id user@192.168.0.1` if the connection would come from `user@192.168.0.1`?

Comment: If the connection would _go to_ `user@192.168.0.1`.  You run the commands on the host you would connect _from_.

Comment: This would be ideal, but then you could even use the ~/.ssh/config and have an entry there with an alias so you could just `ssh server1` and it will do a `ssh user@server1.example.com` and pass off the key for authentication

Comment: True, but that's getting a little bit past the request for a one-liner to set up key-pair SSH authentication (:

Answer (score 7):

You can setup `ssh-keys`, which let you login to your server without any password.
Copy your PC's sshkey from `~/.ssh/idrsa.pub` to the server you want to connect to, using `ssh-copy-id user@host`.

This will let your PC connect to the server without a password using the option `ssh -A user@host`

If `idrsa.pub` does not exist, you can create it using the command `ssh-keygen`

This might not be a one liner, but this can solve your issue. and is quite easy to setup.

Answer (score 1):

The answers given here are right, but when you are writing script for this, simple `scp`  doesn't work. Because you need to allow server's public key(fingerprint) for connecting the first time. So when writing the script you need to bypass that by adding  `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`  option.
So now your one-liner will be `ssh-copy-id -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@host.example.com`

and if have not created your ssh-keys yet then `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/ -q -P "" & ssh-copy-id -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@host.example.com`